# Whitelist allow for specific requests Nginx

Tags: nginx, whitelist

I have a server and there is a Nginx in front. There are many requests which some of them contains special word example:

```
/posts/men/clouths
```

I have a whitelist ip file also. I want to write a rule in Nginx that if requests contains "**men**", only allow the request if requester's ip is in whitelist file.
If requests does not contains "**men**" allow the request anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Done

```
http {
    ## load whitelist
      map $remote_addr $deny {
        default 0;
        include /path/to/whitelist.txt;
}

server{
    ## check
    set $is_white_list 0;
    if ($request_uri ~ ".*men.*"){
      set $is_white_list 1;
    }
    if ($deny) { 
      set $is_white_list 1$is_white_list;
    }
    if ($is_white_list = 1) {
      return 403;
    }
    ##// epg check
}
```